# Adding checkboxes column for each row in table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-table

Hello how can I add a new column with checkboxes for each row on the left side of my `id` column.

```
export default function Display() {
  const { menus } = JsonData;

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Id",
        // accessor: "id"
        accessor: (row) => row.id
      },
      {
        Header: "Title",
        accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),        
        Cell: ({ value }) => (
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${value.id}` }}>{value.title}</Link>
        )
      }
    ],
    []
  );

   return (
    <Table
      data={menus}
      columns={data}
      withCellBorder
      withRowBorder
      withSorting
      withPagination
    />
  );
}
```

Here is my [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/filters-forked-kgvzbt?file=/src/Display.jsx:0-908)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new column to your data :

```
const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        id: "check",
        accessor: (row) => row.title,
        Cell: ({ value }) => <input type="checkbox" value={value} />
      },
      {
        Header: "Id",
        // accessor: "id"
        accessor: (row) => row.id
      },
      {
        Header: "Title",
        // accessor: "title"
        accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),
        // accessor: (row) => (
        //   <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${row.id}` }}>{row.title}</Link>
        // )
        // Link the content of my cell. NOT WORKING
        //Cell: ({ row }) => (
        //<Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${row.id}` }}>{row.title}</Link>
        //)
        Cell: ({ value }) => (
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${value.id}` }}>{value.title}</Link>
        )
      }
    ],
    []
  );
```

[image: Edit filters (forked)]

Comment: Is there a way to have an empty header for my checkbox column please ? I've tried  `{Header: "", accessor: (row) => row.id, Cell: ({ value }) => <input type="checkbox" value={value} />` but I have an blank page.  And why doing `accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),` and not only `accessor: (row) =>row.title,` ?

Comment: @Zokulko Please check answer again!

Comment: Why do you have to write `accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),` an d not only `accessor: (row) => row.title,` for Header:"Title" ??

Comment: @Zokulko I've copied your  code from your question!

Comment: Yes sorry I have updated my code and remove this part, but I've forgot sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new entry into the array:

```js
export default function Display() {
  const { menus } = JsonData;

  const data = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Ceckbox",
        // accessor: "id"
        accessor: (row) => row.id,
        Cell: ({ value }) => (
          <input type='checkbox' />
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "Id",
        // accessor: "id"
        accessor: (row) => row.id
      },
      {
        Header: "Title",
        accessor: (row) => ({ title: row.title, id: row.id }),        
        Cell: ({ value }) => (
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${value.id}` }}>{value.title}</Link>
        )
      }
    ],
    []
  );

   return (
    <Table
      data={menus}
      columns={data}
      withCellBorder
      withRowBorder
      withSorting
      withPagination
    />
  );
}
```